# How do I change a list into integers on Python?

Tags: string, integer

I have a list of which i need to change into intergers.

('01/01/2009', '02/01/2009', '03/01/2009', '04/01/2009')

Firstly how do i change this list of strings into integers so the first date would equal 1 then the next 2 and then the next 3 etc. once this has been completed how to I change the Strings to a Float?
how do I remove the first value/date on the list and keep the rest leaving only the next three dates/values.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow.  I think the reason you're getting voted down is because there isn't code in your question.  It's helpful to post what you've tried, what you're getting (even if it's an error) and what you're expecting.  You can edit your question to put in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before anything, make your `tuple` into a `list`. A `list` is easier to work with as it is mutable (modifiable), whereas a `tuple` is not.

```
>>> dates = list(('01/01/2009', '02/01/2009', '03/01/2009', '04/01/2009'))
>>> dates
['01/01/2009', '02/01/2009', '03/01/2009', '04/01/2009']
```

**Request number one, strings of integers:**

```
>>> answer1 = [item[:2] for item in dates]  # Here we slice the string.
>>> answer1
['01', '02', '03', '04']
```

**Request number two, floats:**

```
>>> answer2 = [float(item) for item in answer1]   # Conversion is easy as that.
>>> answer2
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

*However the above solutions could be concatenated as such:*

```
>>> final = [float(item[:2]) for item in dates]   # A list comprehension.
>>> final
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

**Request number three, delete first `list` item:**

```
>>> final.pop(0)  # Removes and returns an item at the specified index.
1.0
>>> final
[2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

Comment: @user3403282 Huh? I don't understand you but I have improved request one to work for all dates.

Comment: What i mean is the dates I use change but they will always be in order of days of the month chosen. For example `('27/08/2010', '26/08/2010', '25/08/2010', '24/08/2010')` or `(12/12/2006', '11/12/2006', '09/12/2006', '08/12/2006')`. So is it possible to change the date within the list to an integer? so the first date would be 1 and then the second be 2 and so on.

Comment: @user340282 `[dates.index(date)+1 for date in dates]`? If I understand you correctly.

Comment: @user3403282 Yes, just add `[1:]` to the very end of that line. If I have been of assistance please accept by clicking the tick below the vote counts. An upvote is also welcome when you can.

Comment: @user340282 So in that case just do `dates2 = [1:]`.

Answer (score 0):

This will handle dates through December:

```
import operator

dates = ('01/01/2009', '02/01/2009', '03/01/2009', '04/01/2009', '12/01/2009')
getter = operator.itemgetter(slice(0, 2))  # get first two digit characters
print tuple(float(getter(date)) for date in dates[1:])  # leaves first one out
```

Output:

```
(2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 12.0)
```